# Find shape in PDF using Aspose.PDF

Tags: c#, shapes, aspose.pdf

Using C#, I’m analyzing PDF documents in order to check if any texts, images or “objects” are not positioned within a specified margin.

Using word, I create a document including a shape (a basic arrow), images and texts.

I can easily find images and texts but did not manage to retrieve the shape.

Is there a way to retrieve all graphical objects included in a page?

Comment: We believe that we have responded to your similar inquiry over Aspose.PDF support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/t/processing-pdf-content-for-shapes/227413). You may please follow up there. This is Asad Ali and I work as a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Asad. I confirm for my inquiry on Aspose Pdf support forum.
I'll continue on the forum for this question.